# Windows phone with phonegap application click event is not triggerring

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, smartphone

I am developing app using phonegap for windows phone. When I click the button , click event is not seems to be triggering and am not able catch the event.

what could be the reason. Please help in this regard.

Sample Code

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function alertD() {
  }
  function init() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
  $('#bb1').bind('click',function() { 
  navigator.notification.alert('clicked',alertD,'Exit','ok');
  });
  }
  // once the device ready event fires, you can safely do your thing! -jm
  function onDeviceReady(){
  document.getElementById("welcomeMsg").innerHTML += "PhoneGap is ready!";
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="init();">
  <h1> Page </h1>
  <input type="button"  name="b1" id="bb1" value="event" />
  <h1>Hello PhoneGap</h1>
  <div id="welcomeMsg"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Can you paste some of your code, the HTML of the button and the Javascript that is assigning and handling the click event

Comment: Now , i have added the sample code.

Comment: I voted up because I had exactly the same issue and it's very frustrating not to have votes when you make proper questions on this site. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the bind into the deviceReady, also you need to have jquery to use `$().bind`, otherwise you need to use native addEventListener

```
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){
    document.getElementById("welcomeMsg").innerHTML += "PhoneGap is ready!";

    // add the clickHandler function to the click event on #bb1
    document.getElementById("bb1").addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler() {
    navigator.notification.alert('clicked',alertD,'Exit','ok');
}
```

One other thing, you should use `touchstart` or `touchend` for mobile applications, not the `click` event, as that has a 300ms delay whilst waiting to see if it's a double click.

In this case, `touchEnd` would probably be better.

```
    document.getElementById("bb1").addEventListener('touchend', clickHandler);
```

Comment: Oh and move you <script> tags to the end of the document, put them just before the `</body>` tag as they should be run after the HTML has been rendered

Comment: it works , but i am not able have multiple button for alert box like Ok ,Cancel etc

Comment: I think you want "confirm" not "alert": http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.confirm